# Small $x$ expansion of integral (maybe?) related to Bessel functions

Tags: integration, asymptotics, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

Consider

$$\tag{1}
I(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty du \int\limits_{-1}^1dy' \  \frac{e^{-x\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}}{u^2+a^2}\cos(u(y-y'))
$$

For fixed $a>0$ and real $|y|<2$. **I would like to find an approximation for $I$ as $x \to 0$** (or an expression in terms of 'common' non-elementary functions, but I suspect that is not likely).

**My attempt**

I expand the exponential around $x=0$. This of course renders the resulting series divergent, but does facilitate using [Basset's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) to perform each $u$ integral, which is of the form

$$\tag{2}
\int du \ (u^2+a^2)^{-1+n/2}\cos(u(y-y'))
$$

The first few terms of the resulting series are

$$\tag{3}
I\stackrel{?}{\sim}\int\limits_{-1}^1dy' \ \left[\frac{\pi}{a}e^{-a(y-y')}-2xK_0(a(y-y'))+\frac{ax^3}{3(y-y')}K_1(a(y-y'))+\cdots \right]
$$

Where $K$ is a modified Bessel function. The $y'$ integral for the first two terms can now be done using the relations [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43). Since the argument of $K_0$ changes from positive to negative over the integral, I split up the integration and use the [continuation of $K_0$ for negative argument](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.34)

$$\tag{4}
\int\limits_{-1}^1 dy' \ K_0(a(y-y')=\int\limits_{-1}^y dy' K_0(a(y-y'))+\int\limits_y^1 dy' K_0(a(y-y'))
$$

In the second term on the RHS of (4) I express $K_0$ with negative argument using

$$\tag{5}
K_0(-z)=K_0(z)-i\pi I_0(z)
$$

The resulting expression is lengthy, and features Bessel and Struve functions. Here is a plot of $I$ as a function of $y$ using the first two terms of (3) for the approximation versus numerical integration of (1)

[image]

On the left $x=0$, and on the right $x\approx 0.5$. The approximation is good when $y>1$, but becomes complex (for nonzero $x$) when $y<1$. This makes me suspect that the method could be fruitful, but somehow one of the manipulations was not quite right. On the other hand, I am not attached to this method, so any other methods are welcome.

**Background** The integral arises when solving a Laplacian boundary value problem in three dimensions. The $y$ dependence of the result is quite important, while the $x$ dependence less so.

Comment: We can integrate out $y'$ and show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} I(x) = I(0) =
\frac {2 \pi} {a^2} \cases {
 e^{-a |y|} \sinh a & $|y| \geq 1$ \\
 1 - e^{-a} \cosh a y & $|y| < 1$}, \\
I'(0) = -2 \int_{\mathbb R} \frac {\sin u \cos y u} {u \sqrt {u^2 + a^2}} du$$
(where $I'$ is the right derivative). The last integral has a closed form in terms of the Meijer G-function.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you. What is the expression for $I'(0)$  in terms of the Meijer G function? (It is not obvious to me, and Mathematica does not integrate it)

Comment: The closed form can be derived by the Mellin convolution method, since $\sin b \sqrt u$ and $1/\sqrt {u + a^2}$ are G-functions with arguments of the form $k u$. We get
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin b u} {u \sqrt {u^2 + a^2}} du =
\frac 1 {2 a} G_{1, 3}^{2, 1} {\left( \frac {a^2 b^2} 4 \middle|
 {1 \atop \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, 0} \right)},
\quad a > 0, \, b > 0.$$

Comment: @Maxim Thank you, I am looking at the convolution method now. However, are you sure there is no typo in your post above? The G function does not match numerically integrating the LHS. I ask because sometime ago I met with a problem where Mathematica *did* integrate something in terms of MeijerG but it was not correct

Comment: What values of $a$ and $b$ are you taking and what values do you get for the lhs and the rhs?

Comment: @Maxim With $a=1$, here is a short table:
$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline b & LHS & RHS \\ \hline 1 & 1.24251 & 0.392575 \\ \hline 2 & 1.47368 & 0.571648 \\ \hline 3 & 1.53995 & 0.579315 \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$

Also, using Mathematica's MeijerGReduce, it seems the arguments of the transforms are not the same. Also, what happens to the $1/u$ in the integral?

Comment: By definition,
$$\frac 1 2 G_{1, 3}^{2, 1} {\left( \frac 1 4 \middle|
 {1 \atop \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, 0} \right)} =
\frac 1 2 \frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{\operatorname {Re} s = -1/4}
 \frac {\Gamma(-s) \Gamma^2 {\left( \frac 1 2 + s \right)}} {\Gamma(1 - s)}
 \left( \frac 1 4 \right)^{-s} ds \approx 1.24251.$$

Comment: @Maxim Am in inputting it correctly? In Mathematica, this is what I have:
$$
\frac{1}{2a} \operatorname{MeijerG}\left[\{ \{ 1 \} ,\{ \} \} ,\{ \{1/2,1/2 \},\{1/2,0 \}  \} ,a^2b^2/4 \right]
$$

Comment: @Maxim I was *not* inputting it correctly. My bad, the LHS = RHS. I still do not see how the convolution works here. $\sin(b\sqrt{u})$ gives a G function of argument $b\sqrt{u}/2$ while $1/\sqrt{u+a^2}$ gives a G function of argument $u/a^2$. It seems to me that neither of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Definite_integrals_involving_the_G-function) are applicable here?